# Number of bronze badges partially visible

Tags: bug, design

This might be a minor bug but I think it counts.

[image]

The "8" of 178 bronze badges is half visible.

Snapshot from [this](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/461/9049) question.

System:

1920x1080(1080p), Firefox v25.0.1 and likewise for 26.0.

Comment: The problem is Caleb's massive rep and badge numbers. Tone it down man! Sheesh. ;)

Comment: I wonder if it is related to this: [Bronze badge number not visible on flagging page](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3268/bronze-badge-number-not-visible-on-flagging-page).

Comment: @Wikis exact same bug, it's basically that our badge icons are wider than on most sites

Comment: @waxeagle so the solution is simply to change the size of our icons and ensure that all icons fit to a required size.